# Specific file for pooling tags in org folder

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

I'm trying to organize tags among many org files.

I have a few tags defined in `init.el` through `org-tag-alist` and other tags placed at top of files.

I would like to set a `tags.org` file for tags in folder `project` (in order to tag any entry regardless which `.org` file from `project` is concerned).

Setting `#+TAGS:` at top of file make org-mode searching `init.el` tags but doesn't load tags from `tags.org`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a case for a directory-local variable for `org-current-tag-alist`. Something like this in a .dir-locals.el file might be what you need.

```
((org-mode
  (org-current-tag-alist
   ("tag1")
   ("tag2"))))
```

Note though, if you also want file local ones, you will have to overwrite them with

```
# Local Variables:
# org-current-tag-alist: (("aa") ("bbbb") ("cccc"))
# End:
```

Comment: I was expecting some go-to solution avoiding to manage local lisp files. I'll give it a try, thanks!